# Why does vector grid creation crash?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector-grid

I'm trying to create a vector grid for a municipality. Do you know why does it crash? The scale I'm using is 1:1000000.

Any tips?

[image]

Comment: How are you creating your grid?

Comment: I just clicked on update extents from layer, set the parameters as in the image and clicked on output grid as polygons. I attached an image of the settings.

Comment: Do you really need to create a grid at 0.1 meter spacing? The grid is going to have >11 billion cells. Do you actually want 0.1 degree spacing?

Comment: hmmm youre right. I changed coordinate system and still learning how to interpret some things. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your settings: extents and cell size, you will notice that the resulting vector file will be huge - obviously bigger than your system can handle. You either need to increase grid spacing or reduce the extent.